# Paypal Payment using IPN method not redirecting after payment

Tags: php, redirect, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have implemented PayPal Payment with IPN method and its working fine. Its making payments and sends the notification back to merchant site. However, after completing the transaction successfully it doesn't redirects customer to success page URL (merchant website). It stays on paypal and doesn't shows any redirect url.

we refer this url for implementation:

http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/paypal-php-integration

Can any one help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to turn auto return `On` in your [PayPal account settings](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/mer/express_return_summary-outside) otherwise the return url is ignored

Comment: I have already refer this url and applied setting in paypal account, but couldn't get the solutions. Anyways thank for reply.

Comment: if any body gets that solution :(